# Post-apocalyptic short film about a world where young people are paired with someone of the opposite sex upon reaching a specific age

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, short-film

I am trying to find a short film from the late '70s or '80s, shown at film festivals and/or scifi conventions. I might have seen it at the Los Angeles International Film Exposition, aka Filmex, or possibly at a science fiction convention in Los Angeles (either Phantasmicon in 1978 or Equicon/Filmcon during that time period).

Plot: The air outside is not breathable. For your 18th (or 16th?) Birthday you are paired with someone of the opposite sex. They first meet on video and the main female character removes her top and asks the male for his opinion. Both teenagers seem a bit shy and awkward. The main male character is looking forward to his first encounter with his new mate but runs into trouble trying to get to her through the outside apocalypse world and doesn't make it. She is then paired with another guy, who is a jerk. I think he says, unenthusiastically, "I'll take it" when she removes her top and she says something like "I'm not an it, I'm a person". I recall they also use an abbreviated form of English with some words shortened.

The director was present at the screening I attended and I remember that he was in a wheelchair. That will hopefully be enough info to identify this film, even though it's a short film.